# JBoss7.1.3 servlet-name in web.config produced ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet

Tags: maven, jsf-2, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

I'm trying to create a javaee6 ear application in jboss7.1.3 using javaee6-api, jsf-api-2.1.19 and unfortunately I can't get around this issue, whenever I specified

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

JBoss is throwing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet from [Module "deployment.myApp.ear.myApp-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
```

The jsf jars are in my war and ear project. And I've specified:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

For the app to use my packaged jsf.

But when I removed the servlet the app is successfully deployed. Any idea?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me for this problem was to removed the extra configuration in maven war plugin, the same also causes the Mojarra tear down problem.

This is what's left:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```